# Is it possible to hide all DOM within a specified form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to hide all elements in a form, except one(legend).

```
 <form class="common">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>General Info</legend>
    <div class="group">
    <label>First:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <label>Middle:
       <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <label>Last:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <label>Age:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>General Info</legend>
    <div class="group">
    <label>First:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <label>Middle:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <label>Last:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <label>Age:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
   </fieldset>
```

I'm looking to hide everything within the form, except the legends of each fieldset, which when click I want to show that fieldsets elements.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Bonus if you could get this to only allow 1 fieldset open at once.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: What about `form.hidden > *:not(fieldset:first-of-type) { display: none; }`?

Comment: Could have, but doesnt solve full problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, close the DIV tags on your markup, then do it like this:

```
$(function() {
    // This bit could be avoided if you set display: none on your CSS
    $('.common fieldset > :not(legend)').hide();

    // One fieldset open a time, when click the legend
    $('.common fieldset > legend').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('div').toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NRd3q/

Demo (with the CSS change): http://jsfiddle.net/NRd3q/1/

Comment: This hides everything nicely, but the click is not opening / toggling the fieldsets. I also had to change .on to .bind. Any ideas?

Comment: I just double checked the jsFiddle and it works just fine. What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.common fieldset > :not(legend)').hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6uMWK/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this quick demo, should do the job (only shows one fieldset at a time):

```
function hideAll(){
    $("fieldset > :not(legend)").hide();
}

hideAll();

$("fieldset").click(function(){
    hideAll();
    $(this).children().show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VYwut/2/

Comment: Could you find a way to contain this to just this form, their are more than 1 form on this page.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide every `fieldset` node under the `div` with `class="common"`:

```
$('.common > fieldset > :not(legend)').hide();
```